# sqldatasource - UpdateParameters with image byte array

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload, sqldatasource

This is how you set the defaultValue with a string:

```
sqlDataSource.UpdateParameters["Active"].DefaultValue = tbActive.Text;
```

How do you do something similar to the code below so that my `sqlDataSource` can accept an updated image?

```
FileUpload fuRoom1 = (FileUpload)gvRoom.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("UploadedFile11");
        byte[] imageData1 = new byte[fuRoom1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length + 1];
        fuRoom1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageData1, 0, imageData1.Length);

sqlDataSource.UpdateParameters["Image1"].DefaultValue = imageData1;   
//<--wont work because it's not a string any ideas?
```

I have to save an image into a SQL database as datatype Image from the `RowUpdating` event of a gridView.  I have a FileUpload control in an `EditItemsTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Handle the OnUpdating event of your sqlDataSource and set the value there.